# What changes when a process runs over X server

Tags: linux, bash, jvm, x11, xorg

Today I have a Java system running as a backend service in a Linux server without any window manager. It works like a charm! :)

Now, for silly reasons that make no difference to the discussion, I have to run such system over a X server! I mean, I'm gonna open a xterm and do what I usually do in my Linux server.

My question is: is there any point I must take into consideration from now on, regarding memory allocation or processing aspects, just because it is running over a X server?

Comment: The answer lies in what “running over a X server” actually means.

Comment: @Holger: It's just a Java process launched thru a bash script (Java + OSGI standalone application). It receives request in a socket interface, goes to DB sometimes, and returns.

Comment: And what does “*running over a X server*” actually mean?

Comment: @Holger: Means that instead of just execute my bash script directly on linux shell, I'll run it in a xterminal (inside a X server) in the same way.

Comment: If you start a process in a shell within an xterminal, you are still running on the client and only the inherited environment variable `DISPLAY` will tell that there is an associated display connection you could use. Unsetting the variable will discard that knowledge. Likewise, you could set the variable for a process not running in an xterminal to direct it to the same display device (might require further security relevant steps). In other words, processes started in an xterminal are not running in a special mode or such alike. But you may add `-Djava.awt.headless=true` to the command line…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any point I must take into consideration from now on, regarding memory allocation or processing aspects, just because it is running over a X server?

»No«.

Your application obviously doesn't open any window, otherwise it wouldn't work headless. So the X server never gets involved with your program. Even if it did, it's Java's job to take care of these things, really.

For all intents and purposes your program will be running just as before (assuming it doesn't *rely* on the absence of a display server).

Comment: Right! There is no references in the code about any thing related to X server. Are you saying, in that case, my code would even know that is running inside a X server? I mean, X sever wouldn't be a kind of layer between my code and the rest of SO calls/accesses, right?

Comment: No, the X server is not a layer between your app and your OS.